# Numbers not detected in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I tried to create a Dashboard to represent COVID-19 data set which is available at https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

During that process I created a Pie Chart with `New Cases` (COVID-19) and the highest value shown is 602, which is not the case (highest value should be 10,192 as of now).

Please refer the image of the Dashboard and the Data Set.

***Hint***: 602 is the highest value which is less than 1000 and in the worldometer website numbers are formatted with thousand separator. I can not find a solution but I think this is something to do with that thousand separator.

**This is the Dashboard - Please refer the table & pie chart (left)**:

[image: 1]

**This is my Data Set - Please look for New Cases Column**:

[image: 2]

**This is my Data Source - New Cases Field is with Number Data Type**:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `New Cases` field is currently recognised as a `Text` field in Google Sheets (Data Set), thus the comma in `+10,192` is a literal comma; one way in the Data Set is to change the format from `Plain Text` to `Number`, alternatively, it could be achieved in Google Data Studio:

### 1) Type: Text

At the [Data Source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6268208), set the Type of the `New Cases` field to `Text`.

### 2) `GDS_New Cases`

Create the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below and use the `GDS_New Cases` field instead of `New Cases`

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(New Cases, "[\\+,]","") AS NUMBER)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/26b5b307-13bd-436b-b3de-623b03cd00d5) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]